# crop image in cell uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Is it possible to trim the bottom of the image that extend beyond the frame. I've got an image height of 280px, and the frame is targeted at 240px, if you compress the height, the image loses its quality.
I turned on the mode - Aspect Fit and enable "Clip Subviews" and also have auto-layout within the maximum image height 240px

In the pictures, the text must be below the pictures, but not inside it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: how are you getting this image? It would be far more easier, if you do the cropping outside the app. Unless you change the image frames frequently in your app, I suggest you to use images with required size.

Comment: You can try starting with this :https://github.com/iosdeveloper/ImageCropper

Comment: @Mr.T I get the picture using SDWebImage, then process them using the resize, change the width and height of myself believe. but it can be greater than the image height of the cell

Comment: so you process the image before you display it ?

Comment: @user2759544 it shouldn't matter how you preprocess the image. If you have aspect fill on the imageview, then the image shouldn't go outside of the imageview even if you don't have clip subviews active. In my opinion the imageview is actually bigger and goes under the label. Or maybe the imageview height is OK and the label is moved to the top for some reason. Can you check if there is not some auto layout problem? Maybe some constraints are deleted because they are in conflict?

Comment: Is your image always in the ratio of the imageview? or rather i should ask, is your image's width always that of your imageview's Width? and is the height the only thing that is out of bounds?

Comment: @SahebRoy yes, the width of the image coincides with the width uiimageview. and the height is automatically set